# Issue with SOAP Request to Web Service

Tags: php, web, soap, service

I have to do a request to a Web Service using SOAP with POST method and I have an example XML they provided, which I have to use for the Request to the WS, and no more information about, how to do it? 
The Web Service I'm trying to access is for authentication purposes, and PHP code I'm trying includes the login and password info.

```
<?php
$usuario = "login";
$password = "pass";


$strXml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org        /soap/envelope/\' xmlns:guia=\'link to .wsdl\'>
                            <soapenv:Header/>
                                <soapenv:Body>
                                    <guia:infoUser>
                                    <guia:nif>userNIF</guia:nif>
                                    </guia:infoUser>
                                </soapenv:Body>
                            </soapenv:Envelope>";


                                                $wsdl = 'LINK TO WSDL???.wsdl';
                                        $namespace = 'Here i think i need to put the link that goes to the part of auth on the wsdl';
                                        $credentials = (object)array(
                                            'login' => $usuario,
                                            'pass' => $password
                                        );
                                        $auth_values = new SoapVar($credentials, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
                                        $header =  new SoapHeader($namespace, "authGUIA", $auth_values);

                                        // set client, headers, and call function
                                        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => true));
                                        $client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```

I have tried so many things, and  I do not know, what else to try? I did many tests and some will give me the message "You must use POST and not GET method because the password would be stored in logs".

If someone can enlighten me with an explanation/solution for my problem in case some of my code is correct, I will be very grateful.

Thanks.